# Group with less than $1000$ elements generated by less than $10$ elements

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that a group with order less than $1000$ is generated by fewer than $10$ elements?

Comment: Perhaps it follows from $\;2^{10}=1,024\;$ and $\;(\Bbb Z_2)^{10};$ being the "smallest" elementary abelian group...

Answer (score 7):

Suppose otherwise. Let $a_1, a_2, \dots a_{10}$ be distinct elements of a generating set.

Consider the products $a_ia_k \dots a_r$ where the product may be empty, but we otherwise have $i\lt k \lt \dots \lt r$ - i.e. the suffices are strictly increasing.

Observe

1. There are more than $1000$ of these products
2. Therefore two distinct products are equal
3. Therefore we can write one generator as a non-trivial product of the others
4. Therefore we can reduce the number of generators
5. Therefore we can generate the group with fewer than $10$ generators.

Note that the group $C_2^9$ of order $512$ requires nine generators.

Comment: This argument shows that any group of order $n$ can be generated by at most $\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$ elements.